# Compare my iTunes library with the iTunes Store's

Tags: itunes, applications, applescript

Is there a way to compare my iTunes library with the iTunes Store's library, so I can find what songs I'm missing by a particular artist?  Ideally, I would be able to compare the Store and my Library by Song Title, Artist or Album name.

I did this manually recently to see what Beatles songs I was missing.  It took a lot of time and printed pages of my iTunes Library just to find the names of the 7 songs that I needed.  There must be some easy way to let the computer do the search and comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and honestly I didn't find a great method to do this, just a plethora of different items. 
If you activate your iTunes sidebar, you can actually go to the album in the iTunes store directly when you are playing or selecting that song.

You can also use things like iTunes preview to compare against your iTunes library, for instance [The Beatles](http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/the-beatles/id136975?trackPage=2#trackPage) page has their songs and albums (though they are called top songs and albums) and you can click on any of them to get a track list.

I found I could copy and paste the track list to a spreadsheet application like numbers while preserving the formatting, and could do the same with an iTunes library exported track list (as text), I then sorted by columns and saw the ones I did have against the ones in the albums on iTunes next to each other.

This isn't a great approach, but it seems like it will take significantly less time than manually printing out song lists and the like, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing out pages, you could export your iTunes library (or a relevant portion thereof) into a CSV file which you can then import into Excel or Numbers.

This would make searching and finding things that you have easier and faster, and save paper to boot.